# python: integer to string conversion

Tags: python, string

I have been trying to convert an integer into a string. My codes are as follows:

```
n = 357
x = str(n)
print x
```

The problem is that online editors that I have tried are not printing the string as '357'. Instead the string is printed as 357. What have I been doing wrong?

Comment: "What have I been doing wrong?" Nothing. That's how strings are printed when using `print`. What significance do the `'` have here? If you want the `'` printed use `print repr(x)`.

Comment: `''` defines a string literal but is not part of the string's characters. By default, `print` only *prints* the contained characters.

Comment: when you print your string x using print function it will not include quotes. it just prints string's value only. But you can see whether value is string or int by checking `print type(x)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You apparently want to print the **representation** of the string. Python has a builtin function [**`repr(..)`**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#repr) for this:

```
n = 357
x = str(n)
print(repr(x))
```

The representation of a string is a list of characters between single or double quotes (double quotes if the string contains at least one single quote and no double quotes). Furthermore if there are escape sequences (like a new line), these are printed with a backslash (like `\n`).